# Firebase Authentication does not work on Android device

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am trying to authenticate users with Firebase.

Earlier I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520551/gameobject-setactive-inside-firebase-authentication-not-called).
In that question, it was a problem that occurred in both the Unity editor and the Android actual machine.

However, the answer to that question only worked in Unity's editor.

The following code calls `PushedButton ()` when the button is pressed and reads `RegisterUser (string, string)`.

```
public void PushedButton()
{
    string Email, Password; //is substituted
    StartCoroutine(RegisterUser(Email, Password));
}
IEnumerator RegisterUser(string email, string password)
{
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    var registerTask = auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => registerTask.IsCompleted);

    if (registerTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Failed to register task with {registerTask.Exception}");
        Obj.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log($"Successfully registered user {registerTask.Result.Email}");
    }
}
```

But these two lines are not called on Android devices:

```
Debug.LogWarning ($ "Failed to register task with {registerTask.Exception}");
```

*and*

```
Debug.Log ($ "Successfully registered user {registerTask.Result.Email}");
```

What is the difference between an editor and an Android device? I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try resolving android dependencies.

`Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Force Resolve`